# error while attempting to save data to firebase using reactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to save data in firebase realtime database, but when I run the page and try to submit my inputs, an error will be shown says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rVsn.png). I don't know if I did it correctly in this.state. I have an idea of getting the values inside my  but I don't know how to handle such values and passed on sates.

```
class SideNav extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            fullname: '',
            purok: '',
            userType: 'purokLeader'
        }
    }

    state = {
        open: false,
    };

    onOpenModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    onCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    signOut() {
        firebaseApp.auth().signOut();
    };



    signsUp() {


        firebaseApp.database().ref('Usersyeah/').push({
            name: this.state.fullname,
            purok: this.state.purok,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            user: "purokLeader"

        });

    };

    render() {
        const { open } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container">

                <div className="sidebar" style={sideBarColor}>
                    <div className="logoCont">
                        <img src={logo} className="sideLogo"/>
                    </div>

                    <Link to="/" ><img src={home} style={{width: '30px'}} alt="Log Out image"  /> Dashboard</Link>
                    <Link to="/docproc"> Document Services</Link>
                    <Link to="/sumbong"> Sumbong Center</Link>
                    <Link to="/announce"> Announcement</Link>
                    <div style={{ marginTop: ''}} ><Link to="#" onClick={() => this.onOpenModal()}><img src={logoutIcon} style={{width: '30px'}} alt="Log Out image"  /> Add User</Link></div>

                    <div style={{ marginTop: '35px'}} ><Link to="#" onClick={() => this.signOut()}><img src={logoutIcon} style={{width: '30px'}} alt="Log Out image"  /> Log out</Link></div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} >
                        <h4>Simple centered modal</h4>
                        <input name="Name" id="fullname" type="text" ref="Fname" placeholder="Enter Your Fullname..." style={mainDivInput}     onChange={event => this.setState({ fullname: event.target.value })}/>
                        <input id="PurokNum" type="text" ref="PurokNum" placeholder="Purok No."  style={mainDivInput}    onChange={event => this.setState({ purok: event.target.value })}/>
                        <input id="email" type="email" ref="Email" placeholder="Enter Your Email..."  style={mainDivInput}    onChange={event => this.setState({ email: event.target.value })}/>
                        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" ref="Pword" placeholder="Enter Your Password..." style={mainDivInput}   onChange={event => this.setState({password: event.target.value })} />


                        <div>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{height: '40px', marginTop: '100px', marginLeft: '330px'}} onClick={this.signsUp} >Create</button>&nbsp;

                        </div>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }


}

export default withRouter(SideNav) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused because of `this`, change your `signsUp()` function at an arrow function

```
signsUp = () => {
        firebaseApp.database().ref('Usersyeah/').push({
            name: this.state.fullname,
            purok: this.state.purok,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            user: "purokLeader"

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

As Praveen mentioned use arrow function or manually bind the function in constructor

You need to either manually bind the function or Turing to an arrow function to access state or props inside that function

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        fullname: '',
        purok: '',
        userType: 'purokLeader'
    }
    this.signsUp = this.signsUp.bind(this);
}
```